# How to change toolbar action icons in PE.SDK for react-native?

Tags: react-native, photoeditorsdk, imglykit

I'm using the photo editor SDK (react-native) from IMG.LY for editing images; however, I would like to change the default toolbar icons. Is there any way to do it?
[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLz9U.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS:**
In order to exchange icons in the editor on iOS, you need to provide an image block that is available natively for the `PESDK` class:

First, you need to import the `RNPhotoEditorSDK` header inside your `AppDelegat.m`/`AppDelegate.mm` file:

```
#import <RNPhotoEditorSDK/RNPhotoEditorSDK.h>
```

Then, you can set the image block before the editor is opened. We recommend placing the code inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in the same file.

```
[PESDK setBundleImageBlock:^UIImage * _Nullable(NSString * _Nonnull identifier) {
  if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"imgly_icon_save"]) {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgly_icon_approve_44pt"];
  }
  return nil;
}];
```

**For Android:**

You will need to create custom resource files for the corresponding icons of the SDK. Simply provide a resource file with the same filename as used in the SDK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M20.999994 7l-1.4 -1.4 -10.6000001 10.6 -4.2 -4.2 -1.4 1.4 5.6 5.6z"
        android:fillColor="?attr/imgly_icon_color_secondary" />
</vector>
```

This information can be found [here](https://img.ly/docs/pesdk/react-native/guides/user-interface/customize-icons/#customize-icons).